# Bringing a MKPolygon to the front

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am drawing a bunch of MKPolygons in my MKMapView. Some of them lay on top of each other. How can I bring a selected polygon to the top/front?

I tried `bringSubviewToFront:` on a MKPolygonView I create from the polygon layer:

```
MKPolygonView *view = (MKPolygonView *)[self.mapView viewForOverlay:polygon];

view.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

SOLUTION:

I removed

```
MKPolygonView *view = (MKPolygonView *)[self.mapView viewForOverlay:polygon];

view.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

and replaced it with what Craig suggested:

```
[self.mapView insertOverlay:polygon atIndex:self.mapView.overlays.count];
```

which then calls the MKMapKit delegate `mapView:viewForOverlay:` and then I handle the color change there:

```
    - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]] && !((MKPolygon *)overlay).isSelected) {
        MKPolygonView*    aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
    }
    else if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]] && ((MKPolygon *)overlay).isSelected) {
        MKPolygonView*    aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an overlay to a mapView you can choose where to place it in the list of overlays. Since an overlay can only be in the list once you can move it just by inserting again at the desired location. Since you want it at the top, this should work:

```
[mapView insertOverlay:overlay atIndex:[mapView.overlays count]];
```

You should not be calling viewForOverlay. Leave that to iOS. If you need to colour the overlay do it within viewForOverlay because iOS can and will call that when ever it wants and if you return a non-coloured overlay that's what it will draw.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Without this line of code, if I select the polygon that is on the top, the stroke color does change. With the code, the top polygon does not become visible (the stroke color does not change, either its being reomved and placed somewhere it can't be shown or the stroke color isn't taking effect /baffle).

Comment: more info: I keep a pointer to the "selected" polygon (ie, orange border color). When I try to "deselect" (ie, change it back to yellow), I get an error when I try to alter the saved polygon: `reason: '-[CALayer levelsOfDetail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91d1620'`

Comment: I do use the `viewForOverlay:` delegate where I set the border to yellow. After it is draw, I detect a tap within the polygon and want to change the border color. The only way I was able to figure out was to put the polygon into a MKPolygonView again. Should I be doing it a different way?

Comment: Well so long as your viewForOverlay also sets the selected item to yellow too then you should be alright. But if you don't do it in there the mapview can and will call viewForOverlay itself and redraw your item as not yellow.

Comment: I think `viewForOverlay:` is only called when an overlay is added. Should I remove the polygon, add the polygon and handle the color change in `viewForOverlay:`?

Comment: That should work. But aren't you moving it to the top using the insertOverlay function I gave you above? That will prompt it to be redrawn

Comment: Yep, you're right. Instead of handling the color change in my `selectBoundary:` method, I take the boundary, insert at top and the `viewForOverlay` delegate gets called. I handle the color change there which works perfect. Thanks!